# How to decode javascript file using perl script?

Tags: javascript, tomcat

I obfuscated javascript files using stunnix tool through buildscript which is perl script.How to decode the obfuscated file using perl??

Comment: Prevent easy decoding is what obfuscation is meant for. If a simple script was enough to unobfuscate, there would be no interest in obfuscating.

Comment: i cant help it..thats the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can't.

You could parse the JavaScript AST and then pretty-print it, which would go a long way towards improving its readability, but you cannot, for example, recover the original variable names or function names.

Comment: we can use malzilla but it takes one file at a time